# git / Bitbucket revision control misunderstanding

Tags: git, workflow, bitbucket

I'm developing a site on my local machine, and then pushing the changes to a remote server when they're ready. This is my workflow:

1. Develop locally
2. When the changes are made, add the files (git add newfile.abc etc.)
3. Commit the files (git commit -m "Adding newfile.abc")
4. Run git push origin master
5. Go to Bitbucket, see the commit, Approve it, then jump over to my server.
6. On the server, run git pull origin master

However, I've noticed that the master branch contains all the changes after step 4 (running git push origin master), before I have Approved the commit on Bitbucket.

There is something I'm not understanding here... can anyone clarify or point out ways I could improve my current workflow? Thank you!

Comment: It would b hard to suggest improvements without knowing what you're trying to accomplish with your workflow.  So, what would you like your workflow to help you accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approve button is not really needed for the commit to go into the Bitbucket repository, it is simply used for reviewers to indicate their approval (see https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/119324/user-is-asked-to-approve-commit-on-bitbucket). You should be able to skip step 5 in your workflow without any issues.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate any opportunity to simplify my workflow.